# how to find references to a method in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I am reading through a very large and complex ios app project, I want to find the places in the code when a certain function (or method) is called. 
I've seen some answers for older xcodes where you can filter your search results to only show you references. But I dont see this option in xcode 5.
so possibly 2 questions:
1- is there a way to enable these search options?
2- are there any other ways to search for all references to a method (or any symbol).

Answer (score 1):

If you click the search icon and the click where it says "In workspace". It should bring across a menu that will allow you to select specific groups and folders. You can also create a "new scope" to use for searching more complex rules.

Comment: Thank you but, seems like these options all have to do with the file type and location. I'n looking for a smart search that doesnt just look for the string I searched for, but rather recognizes the symbol object and shows me the call to it. So for example it wouldn't show me occurrences where the string appears in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 6, you can open the Find Navigator (⌘-3) then where it says `Find > Text > Containing`, these items are clickable and you can change it to `Find > References > Containing`.

Alternatively, with your cursor inside a method you can click the icon   in the top left corner of the editor (it looks like four squares) and choose `Callers`.